# Data not being updated by cron job

Tags: php, pdo, cron

I am using a cron job to take totals from a transaction table and update another table.
In my cron job email I am returning that the task completed but didnt see a change in my data.

```
    <?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=the", 'the', '1');
        $query = "UPDATE Test a 
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT ID, SUM(Total) as Total, 
                    FROM TestTrans
                    WHERE Status = ? 
                    Group By ID
                ) b
                ON a.ID = b.ID
        SET a.Total = b.Total
    Where a.Total > b.Total";

    $iStatus = 1;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $iStatus);

    $stmt->execute();    

    echo 'Task Completed';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Does it update the database if you run it by hand?

Comment: Does the code work fine when you run it from the command line? Does the SQL work when you run it on the database directly? What does `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo())` print?

Comment: Did you try to echo SQL error information? `var_dump($STMT->errorInfo());`

Comment: hmm for somereason when i run it on my db i get #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM TestTrans WHERE Status = 1 Group By' at line 1

Comment: there is a comma after asTotal ?

Comment: @jvdBerg yeah i just noticed that thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- run the scrip manually, from the command prompt in the same way the cron does. e.g. `php myscript.php myoptions`. Does it work?
- add some logging to your cron job:

*/5   * * * * php myscript.php myoptions >> /var/log/cronrun.log 2&>1

Look in the /var/log/cronrun.log file for errors and clues/